# Writing shapefile field values to txt file using SearchCursor?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

I'm having trouble finding a way to write the output of a SearchCursor function to a txt. file. I can print it just fine in a format that is desirable. I just don't know how to get from there to a txt. file. Here's my code below:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "G:\Geocomputation_Project\Section C\Lin_Ref_test"
shape = "Points.shp"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(shape)
f = open("test_field.txt", "w")
for row in cursor:
    print (row.getValue("ITEMID")),(row.getValue("New_X_LRR")),  (row.getValue("New_Y_LRR")) 
print "done"
```

The txt file does not yet exist. When I start running this script, I hope to be able to overwrite the text file as I do more iterations.

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2

Comment: You should always use [data access (DA) cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//018w00000008000000) with 10.1 or higher ArcGIS releases.  The rest of this isn't GIS-centric, just [how file I/O works in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html), and therefore more appropriate for StackOverflow. Please be sure to ask only one question per Question.

Comment: Yes, `"w"` overwrites it (`"a"` is for appending). Yes, you'll want a complete path for `open`. It's not aware of the arcpy workspace. [This](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72458/export-list-of-values-into-csv-or-txt-file/72476#72476) (+ many other questions) should get you started with dumping to disk.

Comment: There seem to be even more questions emerging in comments, and as @Vince said at the outset there should be only one question per question as per the [Tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inserted the lines you require in between:

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"G:\Geocomputation_Project\Section C\Lin_Ref_test"

# Delete prior output if it exists
# Insert a line that creates a variable for the text file
try:
    os.remove("C:\\temp\\output1.txt")
except OSError:
    pass
print("output1.txt deleted")
outtext = r'C:\temp\output1.txt'  # here supply your path and filename

# Then your code
shape = "Points.shp"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(shape)
openfile = open(outtext, 'a')
for row in cursor:
    print row.getValue("ITEMID"), row.getValue("New_X_LRR"), row.getValue("New_Y_LRR") 
    # Then out put the stuff you want to print into the text file
    # (I used new line here you can change how you can concatenate
    # the rows. For example if you want to join them with a ','
    # then change the '\n' part into ','.)
    openfile.write(
        str(row.getValue("ITEMID")) + ' ' +
        str(row.getValue("New_X_LRR")) + ' ' +
        str(row.getValue("New_Y_LRR")) + '\n'
    )
print "done"
openfile.close()
```

I've found an efficient pythonic if exists line from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840533/most-pythonic-way-to-delete-a-file-which-may-not-exist) credit for that goes to SE user Matt

Comment: btw.. it doesn't help to have space in workspace paths..like the space between 'Section' and 'C'.  `"G:\Geocomputation_Project\Section C\Lin_Ref_test`

Comment: Having spaces in workspace paths doesn't hurt (except in really strange circumstances).

Comment: not best practice though.. you never know, when strange circumstances happen

Comment: @yanes did you mean to leave in "f = open("test_field.txt", "w") or should i remove that?

Comment: Sorry I meant to remove that, and I just typed it in just to give you an Idea, let me test it, i'm sure there are a couple of brackets missing too.

Comment: @yanes, I wouldn't go as far to say it's "best practice" to not use spaces. Windows itself uses default system folders with spaces.

Comment: @StephenE - it should work now. there was one bracket missing. Also, I've made all the values into string, as the data I was using as an example had mixed formats. remove the 'str'-s for the fields that do not need conversion in your case.

Comment: @Paul things obviously changed much :). our prof used to go mad if he saw spaces in our codes. this is when we used AML  for Arcinfo Workstation. I'd assume it still is a risk if you interact with the ArcGIS system with your code.. for example if you are using your script as a tool in ArcGIS. As a standalone it probably is okay. I will remember to come here and post an example when I see it happen :)

Comment: @yanes I get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: did you run the last edited version? make sure, you have str in front of all the fields that are not string. Note the final edit, instead of a comma use '+' between the fields. I tried it it works.
also @nmpeterson made the file with a handle w, I wasn't sure why. did you want to overwrite it?

Comment: From the OP's question:  "I hope to be able to overwrite the text file as I do more iterations."

Comment: @nmpeterson thanks! i didn't see that. Also thank you for making it look readable. it was def. not PEP8 standard in its original format :)

Comment: @yanes yes i wanna turn this into a dynamic geoprocessing workflow in ArcMap so i need it to rewrite after each model run. So I got it to work by adding an extra parenthesis to the end of "str(row.getValue("New_Y_LRR")" and removed one from " '\n')) " (python made me due that last one, sytnax error). However! this only prints the last row of attributes. But when I use 'a' instead, it prints all the rows no problem. I just can't have the script appending the rows over and over again after each run.

Comment: I don't know it is optimal, but you can delete the file before creating it? like an if exists line, and make the handle -a. is that something you'd consider?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Maybe If i provide some context. This searchcursor is pulling new xy coords generated in a previous workflow in the "Points" shapefile. I want these xy coords, along with the itemid to be written to a txt. file so that I can then run a xy to line or points to line tool on them in the next step. These coords will change depending on user input with each run.

Comment: in response: I suggested removing the file all in all and re-creating it at every run (not optimal). But I am not sure why the -w didn't work when you re-run it it should over write the contents. I am trying it now. I updated the code with a line the deletes the file before running it, it needs an 'if exists' part so that it doesn't throw exception if the file is not there.

Comment: Okay if you try the code above you'll see what I mean, I inserted a remove the file line, so that every time you are about to write the coordinates you first delete the table that was generated earlier. I changed the handle back to a. NB it still needs an if exists line. brb

Comment: Added the if..exists part to make sure an exception doesn't stop you if the file is not there. Do not forget to "import os" in the beginning.

Comment: @yanes this works phenomenally. Thank you very much for your expertise.

Comment: @Paul a very basic reference from a course [page](http://www.wwu.edu/huxley/spatial/tut/ArcMap_File_Mgmt.htm#Notes_on_Naming_Files_and_Folders_). re- using spaces in documents. Basically, the space could be mistaken for a delimiter when passed through a command line. It became okay later on as paths are either wrapped by a quotation or are given by a variable. But there are still cases where some tools would parse through the path and hit a space and fail.

Comment: @yanes, the example given has not been relevant to a Windows OS since `XP` (I believe `Vista` changed it to simply `Documents`). The default install location of ArcMap (plus a host of other apps) itself is in a folder with spaces: `Program Files (x86)`!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32018/discussion-on-answer-by-yanes-writing-shapefile-field-values-to-txt-file-using-s).  @StephenE I note that you have not yet taken the [Tour] to learn about the procedures of our focussed Q&A format.